# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I am getting this exception continuously on launch of app :

> 2019-02-18 16:33:14.735 2080-2080/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: assus.oumayma.com.firebasekotlinapp, PID: 2080
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{assus.oumayma.com.firebasekotlinapp/assus.oumayma.com.firebasekotlinapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process assus.oumayma.com.firebasekotlinapp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2786)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1501)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process assus.oumayma.com.firebasekotlinapp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
> at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
> at assus.oumayma.com.firebasekotlinapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6673)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)

and this the code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        signOut.setOnClickListener {
            view: View? -> mAuth.signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this, PhoneAuthenfication::class.java))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logged out Successfully :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
    }
    
    
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (mAuth.currentUser == null) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, PhoneAuthenfication::class.java))
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already Signed in :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } 
    }
    
}
```

```
class PhoneAuthenfication : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_authenfication)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        veriBtn.setOnClickListener { view: View? ->
            progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            verify()
        }
        authBtn.setOnClickListener { view: View? ->
            progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            authenticate()
        }
    }


    private fun verificationCallbacks() {
        mCallbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                signIn(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(verfication: String?, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?) {
                super.onCodeSent(verfication, p1)
                verificationId = verfication.toString()
                progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

        }
    }

    private fun verify() {

        verificationCallbacks()

        val phnNo = phnNoTxt.text.toString()

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phnNo,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            mCallbacks
        )
    }

    private fun signIn(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    toast("Logged in Successfully :)")
                    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
    }

    private fun authenticate() {

        val verifiNo = verifiTxt.text.toString()

        val credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, verifiNo)

        signIn(credential)

    }

    private fun toast(msg: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

the **build.gradle**:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

Comment: Please add the entire content of your both build.gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get an instance of Firebase without initialise it. Please add this line of code before you try to get an instance of Firebase:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

If you are using google service `4.1.0`

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

then update the version to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: How to do in fragment?

Comment: Just add this on your Activity onCreate method then no need to add in Fragment.

Comment: Which version of google service you have currently used?

Comment: then upgrade to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
` and try again.

Comment: thanks it's run when I change classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Comment: @Oumayma please accept this answer if your problem solved.